# .Net 4.0 Parallel foreach loop fails to spawn new threads in "production" application

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, clickonce, parallel-processing

I've got a small WPF C# application that has a Parallel foreach loop at the heart of it. The actual loop doesn't do much expect wait for a network response (it's basically a network scanner), and it works fine running it in in Visual Studio 2010 - the app will ramp up to hundreds of threads, even thousands if I let it run long enough.

Here's the core bit of code:

```
ParallelOptions parallelOptions = new ParallelOptions();
        parallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4; // I've tried changing this all the way up to the maximum

        ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);

        Parallel.ForEach<string>(scanAddresses, parallelOptions,  (toscan,state) =>
 {
    doMyScan(toscan);
 }
```

However, when I 'publish' it out as a "ClickOnce" application, the application doesn't multithread well, or indeed at all, on *some* machines - the thread count never goes above 16 threads regardless of how long it's left. I can't figure out exactly what the common denominator is - I've ruled out the OS (eg XP vs Win7), processors, memory, and whether it's 32 or 64 bit. The application even misbehaves when I download it into my development VM from the production server - so the same app and code that flies under VS2010 crawls when running "live" on the *exactly* the same box as it was developed on. But on other machines it runs as designed, spawning lots of threads, even on the most limited of XP installs.

I'm pretty sure the core code is sound - after all, it works fine on SOME machines, and I have a variation of the same code running fine as a console app - so it's something about the deployment process that's breaking it. Can anyone suggest how to start troubleshooting this?

Comment: By providing code. Usually that helps for people to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ... after all it turned out to be nothing to do with parallelism (although thanks for the comments below, they made interesting reading - I'm definitely no expert myself, I just ploughed in and it seemed to work ;) ).

The issue was down to a limit on half-open TCP connections; I knew this limit existed on XP, but even though it was apparently removed in Win7 it still needs a registry key (`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\ EnableConnectionRateLimiting`) to really remove it. Stranger still, the limit on half-opens didn't apply to the app running under VS - it only limited the connections when it was running as a "real",stand-alone application. All very odd, but problem solved anyway - thanks for all the feedback!

Answer (score 4):

The TPL does not aim to produce the maximum number of threads. It aim to produce the optimal number of threads and this depends on the number of cores on the machine and the current load. There is no point in producing additional threads when current cores are saturated because this will only reduce the performance of the program. I am not sure how you manage to produce thousands of threads in any environment using Parallel Foreach.

Also the TPL should be used for CPU intensive work and not for waiting.

Comment: "Also the TPL should be used for CPU intensive work and not for waiting." Would you mind elaborating? Because I don't think that is necessarily the case.

Comment: The TPL aims to optimize CPU work by using techniques like work stealing. It takes care to reduce CPU cache invalidations and similar issues. If you use it to just wait you do not gain anything from using it. Instead you should be using asynchronous calls and callbacks which will reduce CPU load and memory usage compared to threads.

Comment: but doesn't the TPL, by exposing Task<T>, enable better asynchrony support for things like IO? I'm not trying to say that it's focus is on IO etc, I'm suggesting that the TPL supports both forms equally. I'm also not suggesting that a Parallel.ForEach is the right way to go for the OPs question.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not an expert and I may be wrong.
My understanding is that a Task is just an abstraction of a computation that will be complete in the future. The "Parallel" part is what starts the threads and does the scheduling. Of course you can use TPL to do async work and nothing bad will happen. Worse thing you break the performance of another part of the system that uses TPL for CPU intensive tasks by holding threads.

Comment: Neither am I (an expert), but I'm inclined to agree with you there. I think Parallel *is* mainly for CPU bound tasks, but I also think that is only one part of the TPL. So yeah, I think I am agreeing with you.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx - it seems that this is the part that should be used to wrap async operations in a Task.

Answer (score 0):

I have been under the impression that the Parallel libraries look at your underlying hardware (processors and cores) to determine what degree of parallelism to take on if any at all... Perhaps the machines that are misbehaving only have single processor, single cores?

Comment: But the deployed code misbehaves on the same machine that runs it perfectly when running under VS2010 :(